# Adjust MatLab window focus

Tags: matlab, focus, editor, autofocus

I've done some searching regarding this question but no luck so far, and I'm hoping somene here can help me out.

I'm using MatLab's Editor, but when I run the program, the console is in the main window. Is there a way I can make MatLab open its main window just below the Editor window?

For example, I'm on Chrome and then I open the Editor and run the program. But the main window is still hidden below Chrome. Is there any way I can configure it so that any time I open any MatLab window it makes sure that the main window is below that one?

Please let me know if I didn't make myself clear, and sorry for bad english!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Great... that works just fine! Thanks a lot!
If you want to add this as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to "dock" your window.

There is a little curly arrow in the top right hand corner of each window (pointing to the right and down when the window is floating, if I recall correctly). If I understand your question correctly, that would solve it for you..